# Can Android record what it currently plays at the same time?

Tags: android, audiotrack

I am streaming audio data (music) to `AudioTrack` with `track.write(..)`

While doing this and making user listen to audio through device's speakers(etc..) can I also have that audio recorded by using Android's own audio system? (Android 4.0+) Is it capable of doing this?

Comment: I imagine you could easily test this if you have an Android device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `AudioTrack.write()`, thehn you must be writing from a byte stream. If you have the bytes, you can save them anywhere you'd like. Just write them to a file as well, and you'll have it recorded.

Now, it'll be in raw PCM format, mind you. If you want to convert it to WAV, MP3, OGG, etc, you'll have to do that yourself. There are different ways of doing that, but a search should turn something up.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Yes I have the byte stream but it requires downsampling and I have to find out sample windows and boundaries manually. If Android can do this itself, it will lower the complexity.

Comment: What format are you trying to record to? You may want to look into the MediaCodec class.

Comment: I want to convert into PCM 11khz mono. But I want to do it while AudioTrack is playing (:

Comment: I assume you're playing it in the original format, and want to save only in the 11khz mono? If so, there's no reason you can't do it, but I don't know of anything in the SDK that will do it for you. You'll just have to do the conversion math/writing fast and hope it doesn't introduce stuttering into the playback. A separate buffer and thread for writing could help there.

Comment: @frankish: There's no support for this in Android, so it would have to be done the way Geobits described.